# Function stops working after table sort

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I current have a table that is sorted by DataTables with bootstrap integration. In my final column i have a button group (edit, complete etc) that should call functions when clicked.

The buttons are created using this code in a php while loop, with data-id being the variable that the javascript needs to receive

```
echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"complete btn btn-default btn-xs\" data-id=\"" . $row["id"] . "\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\"></span></button>";
```

Javascript:

```
$(".complete").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    alert(id);
})
```

This works on page load but the minute i sort the table, the functions stop working with no output to console! Any help on why this isn't working?

EDIT:

Sort function

```
/* Datatables */
$("#tasks").dataTable({
    "aoColumns": [
        null,
        null,
        {"sType": "date-uk"},
        {"bSortable": false}
    ]
});
$.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "date-uk-pre": function (a) {
        var ukDatea = a.split("/");
        return (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
    },
    "date-uk-asc": function (a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },
    "date-uk-desc": function (a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
});
/* End */
```

Buttons should be recreated on sort as data is not loaded through ajax

Comment: show your sort function or show your HTML after sort .Try event Delegation `$("document").on("click",".complete",function() {`

Comment: whether the buttons are recreated on sort

Comment: if so use event delegation `$(document).on('click', ".complete", function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    alert(id);
})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should delegate event to table level:

```
$("#tasks").on("click",".complete",function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    alert(id);
})
```