# Bootstrap Table with X-editable elements, problems while sorting

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsfiddle, x-editable, bootstrap-table

I have a problem with Bootstrap Table and X-editable library for in-place editing.
I created a simple example to describe it.

### HTML

```
<table id="table" class="table" data-toggle="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-xs-1" data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
            <th class="col-xs-1" data-field="value" data-sortable="true">Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>
                <span id="note1" data-toggle="#edit1">value 1</span>
                <a href="#" id="edit1"><span>edit</span></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>
                <span id="note2" data-toggle="#edit2">value 2</span>
                <a href="#" id="edit2"><span>edit</span></a>
            </td>
        </tr>   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### JavaScript

```
$('#note1').editable({
    type: 'text',
    url: '/post',    
    pk: 1,    
    title: 'Enter value1', 
    ajaxOptions: {
        dataType: 'json'
    },
    toggle: 'manual',
});

$('#note2').editable({
    type: 'text',
    url: '/post',    
    pk: 1,    
    title: 'Enter value2', 
    ajaxOptions: {
        dataType: 'json'
    },    
    toggle: 'manual',
});

$('#edit1').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#note1').editable('toggle');
});

$('#edit2').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#note2').editable('toggle');
});

//ajax emulation
$.mockjax({
    url: '/post',
    responseTime: 200,
    response: function(settings) {
        if(settings.data.value) {
            this.responseText = '{"success": true}';
        } else {
            this.responseText = '{"success": false, "msg": "required"}';
        }
    }
});
```

You can also find it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/9498/

**So, there are two problems with it:** 
1) I can edit my items and everything is ok with it until I use Bootstrap Table column sortings. Once I sort something - my editable elements become uneditable.
2) If I change old values to any new values and then sort any column - I lose my new values and the old values appear back.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, editable working until sorting, using pagination or any other event concerning the table.

Eventually found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20655239/1114610):

You need to delegate the event to the table, 'editable' being the css class assigned to your editable element.

```
$("#table").on("click",".editable",function() {

    $(this).editable();
  //$(this).editable('toggle');

});
```