# Datatables Interaction Disables Other Javascript Functions

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, datatables

I have an element that opens a modal:

```
<a style="color:#5cb85c" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CallModal" data-id="@item.Supplier.Id" href="#CallModal"  class="fas fa-phone-square"></a>
```

I have a Javascript listener on data-toggle=modal that passes the data-id into a field of id="CallSupplier" in the modal.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a[data-toggle=modal], button[data-toggle=modal]').click(function () {
            var data_id = '';
            if (typeof $(this).data('id') !== 'undefined') {
                data_id = $(this).data('id');
            }
            $('#CallSupplier').val(data_id);
        })
    });
```

That all works great. but, I also have Datatables. Everything works great until i interact with Datatables via searching or pagination, and then the javascript for filling the modal stops working/firing.

Here is the full script element on my page. I'm thinking it has something to do with how I'm defining my JS functions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#SupplierTable').dataTable({
            searching: true,
            lengthChange: false,
            info: false,
            pagingType: "first_last_numbers",
            order: [2, 'desc'],
            pageLength: 5,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: ['copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'],
            "columnDefs": [{ "type": "date", "targets": 2 }]
        });
    });
    //map the data-id fields to the objects
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a[data-toggle=modal], button[data-toggle=modal]').click(function () {
            var data_id = '';
            if (typeof $(this).data('id') !== 'undefined') {
                data_id = $(this).data('id');
            }
            $('#AttachmentSupplier').val(data_id);
            $('#CallSupplier').val(data_id);
            $('#CommentSupplier').val(data_id);
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a very similar post that lead to me answering this.
[Function stops working after table sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655201/function-stops-working-after-table-sort)

I removed $(document).ready() from my function, and now it continues to work even after sorting or paging in Datatables.

```
    $('a[data-toggle=modal], button[data-toggle=modal]').click(function () {
        var data_id = '';
        if (typeof $(this).data('id') !== 'undefined') {
            data_id = $(this).data('id');
        }
        $('#AttachmentSupplier').val(data_id);
        $('#CallSupplier').val(data_id);
        $('#CommentSupplier').val(data_id);
    })
```